# RubyMine debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine

I used rubyMine and want to run debugger but have error what this ,mine and waht need to doing ? [screen](https://postimg.org/image/3r46suwe7/)

```
/home/ivan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/ivan/host/courses/lesson8/bin/rake spec
Testing started at 20:27 ...
/home/ivan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-11.3.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Also I have `ruby-2.3.3`

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
```

but I have rvm too

```
rvm env
export PATH="/home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin:/home/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME='/home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3'
export GEM_PATH='/home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3:/home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME='/home/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3'
export IRBRC='/home/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
export RUBY_VERSION='ruby-2.3.3'
```

What I'm doing wrong ?
How to correct config debugger in Ruby Mine ?

Comment: From the command line, run `gem update bundler`.

Comment: `Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
`

Comment: *Rake* is missing.  Have you run `bundle install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are pointing to the wrong SDK and gems.

Open Rubymine Preferences -> Language & Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems

Select the correct RVM gemset, then press the green tick directly below that panel and apply your changes.

Incidentally, add the following to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`, for debugging support from rubyMine -

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'debase'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
end
```

Comment: ok, why I add break poin but when run debugger IDE not enter in this break point https://postimg.org/image/ofjafy2fr/