# RubyMine unable to recognize rake gem

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, rspec-rails, rubymine

I can’t get rubymine to run my tests even though they work fine on the command line. The problems seem to have started after upgrading some gems. When I hit ctrl+shft+F10 I get this:

```
/Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec /Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/williamjeffries/code/myr-admin/bin/spring rspec /Users/williamjeffries/code/myr-admin/spec/controllers/orders_controller_spec.rb --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter --example "OrdersController a single order a credit card order captured order"
Testing started at 6:08 PM ...
/Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:181:in `rescue in specs': Your bundle is locked to rake (12.0.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of rake (12.0.0) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of rake (12.0.0) that hasn't been removed in order to install. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `specs'
    from /Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:235:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:224:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
    from /Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
    from /Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
    from /Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/williamjeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It seems to think I don’t have rake 12.0.0 but a `gem list rake` reveals that I do:

```
$ gem list rake

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rake (12.0.0, 11.2.2, 10.4.2)
```

I double checked and at time of posting, 12.0.0 is in fact both a valid version and the most recent stable build for rake: https://github.com/ruby/rake/releases

Any ideas why this might be failing and how to get RubyMine to run my tests successfully again?

Comment: Your question is quite similar to a previous one I have answered - please take a look at the solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211518/rubymine-debugger/41212082#41212082 to see if that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to restart RubyMine.