# RubyMine debugger error locked to rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

When I started debugger have error and dont understand what need to do for fix this

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.0, debase 0.2.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:51898
Uncaught exception: Your bundle is locked to rake (12.0.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of rake (12.0.0) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of rake (12.0.0) that hasn't been removed in order to install.
```

Why bunble is locked? I run bundle update, but not help

I go to `run` -> `edit configurate` go to button `bundler` and clik 
`run the script in context of the bundle`

and still have error when run shift + F9 for my test file

```
/home/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 52425 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 53157 -- /home/ivan/host/courses/lesson8/bin/rails test
Testing started at 10:57 ...
/home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `rescue in specs': Your bundle is locked to sprockets (3.7.1), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of sprockets (3.7.1) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of sprockets (3.7.1) that hasn't been removed in order to install. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:173:in `specs'
from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

look small different not like previus error but still I dont can debugger
what mine - Your bundle is locked to sprockets (3.7.1) ?

I restart RubyMine but still have error, look [screen_error](https://postimg.org/image/7ebg0qxbd/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use bundle exec rake on RubyMine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036583/how-do-i-use-bundle-exec-rake-on-rubymine)

Comment: Try `bundle update`

Comment: I try bundle update, but still when run shift + F9 for run debugger have this error

Comment: The solution was to restart RubyMine.

Answer (score 0):

Open Rubymine Preferences -> Language & Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems

Select the correct RVM gemset, then press the green tick directly below that panel and apply your changes.

Incidentally, add the following to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`, for debugging support from rubyMine -

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'debase'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
end
```

Comment: what is your ruby -v?

Comment: That answer looks familiar :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211518/rubymine-debugger/41212082#41212082